# Data content, when read operation fails in C

Tags: c, linux, file

Regarding the C lib function read, is there anything defined what happens to the data, when the read operation fails (count = -1)?? Assume that 'data' still holds the previous value; will it be overwritten in case the the current read operation fails? In my current implementation, debugging shows that the old value remains, but is there something 'officially' defined?
consider the following code:

```
int8_t count = 0;
int fd = open(I2C_BUS, O_RDWR);

if (fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open device: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return(-1);
}
...
count = read(fd, data, length);
if (count < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read device(%d): %s\n", devAddr, ::strerror(errno));
    close(fd);
    return(-1);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate what you are referring to. I am not sure which `read()` you are referring to. C itself does not know it as far as I know.

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html

Comment: If the function fails to read data, what new data should be used to overwrite the buffer? And if the function tells you that no data was read, why should it waste time to fill the buffer with fancy new content? And why would you care at all?

Comment: @Gerhardh: I guess one could imagine a situation where the kernel has already copied a bunch of data into your buffer, but before returning, it gets some indication that the data was invalid, and so it returns -1.  The question is whether such behavior would be legal.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR - it has no standardization and it depends on the filesystem's implementation.**

---

To answer your question, we should first take a look on what happens when you call `read`.

Most of the "basic" functions provided by libc are actually a wrapping for the kernel's system calls. Lets look at the code of libc's `read`, found in `read.c`:

```c
/* Read NBYTES into BUF from FD.  Return the number read or -1.  */
ssize_t
__libc_read (int fd, void *buf, size_t nbytes)
{
  return SYSCALL_CANCEL (read, fd, buf, nbytes);
}
libc_hidden_def (__libc_read)
weak_alias (__libc_read, read)
```

As you can see, libc's `read` actually calls the **syscall** `read`:

```c
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(read, unsigned int, fd, char __user *, buf, size_t, count)
{
    struct fd f = fdget(fd);
    ssize_t ret = -EBADF;
    if (f.file) {
        loff_t pos = file_pos_read(f.file);
        ret = vfs_read(f.file, buf, count, &pos);
        file_pos_write(f.file, pos);
        fdput(f);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The syscall `read` then calls `vfs_read` which is part of the VFS (stands for **V**irtual **F**ile **S**ystem). The VFS is an abstraction layer for file systems. Each file system registers a bunch of callback functions which the VFS knows to call.

For example, lets look at chain of functions called when trying to read a file from **ext4** filesystem:

```
 read()           ---> libc
   |
   |
 __libc_read()    ---> libc
   |
   |
 syscall_read()   ---> kernel; found in linux/fs/read_write.c
   |
   |
 vfs_read()       ---> kernel; found in linux/fs/read_write.c
   |
   |
 new_sync_read()  ---> kernel; found in linux/fs/read_write.c
   |
   |
 generic_file_read_iter() ---> ext4's read function; found in fs/ext/ext4
   |
   |

   ...
```

And it keeps going until the last internal function is called. The return value you receive from calling libc's `read` function is returned from the functions above.

However, it is important to say that most of the filsystems (including ext4!) eventually calls some generic kernel's functions, like the `do_generic_file_read` function found in `mm/filemap.c`.
Back to your question - **it depends on the way the filesystem's has choosen to implement `read()`, and there is no standardization**.

---

**So in the bottom line** - most of the filesystems will treat the buffer similarly in case of an error, but you have no guarantee for it. In practice, your data will probably stay the same as there is no reason for it to change.

And as an advice, if you want to know **exactly** what happens, you can always refer to the kernel's source-code :)

Best regards.